# Python Pandas Question: Compare Excel spreadsheets for equal Matches (example serial number found in columns) and place Output in a New File

Tags: python, pandas

Python Pandas Question:

Looking to search Two Excel spreadsheets for equal Matches (example find serial number found in column('Serial Number') in 'fileA' and a column('Serial Number') in 'fileB') and place the Output in a New File or df.

I apologize if this has already has been addressed previously.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel("OPS Manager Inventory Report.xlsx")
df2=pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")

df1['Advanced Report'].isin(df2['Serial Number']).value_counts(normalize=True)*100

False    83.838384
True     16.161616
Name: Advanced Report, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.